# A data buffer to subscribe and unsubcribe with real-time data using rabbitmq

Tags: stream, buffer, rabbitmq, publish-subscribe

Basically I want to create a data buffer that a client could occasionally subscribe to, get all data from the last while, keep listening on it for real-time data, then unsubscribe after some time, and repeat.

I'm thinking of using a TTL rabbitmq queue that expires. The idea is for a client to occasionally subscribe and unsubsribe from it. When the client subscribe to the queue, it should fetch all available messages on the queue. Then the client would keep on the channel to have real-time data pushed to them.

Is this a good way to go about this? I know how to pub/sub on rabbitmq. how do I make it so it pushes all data on queue everytime a client subscribe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how much data you are talking about.  The drawback to your method is that the queue could fill up with a large amount of data, if the data rate is high and the TTL is set for a long time.  You also have to keep the queue alive.  And you must have one queue alive from the start for every possible subscriber.

I would suggest the [Recent History Exchange](https://github.com/videlalvaro/rabbitmq-recent-history-exchange) perhaps modifying it so that it holds more messages.

Comment: There would just be a few MB of data to buffer for each queue. There wouln't be many subscribers, maybe up to a few.

Comment: your comment is quite vague and I am not sure what you are asking me.  Have you had a look at the recent history exchange?

Comment: yes, it seems to do what I described. will give it a go. thank you